# extract jar content and stored in destination folder

Tags: java, jar

how i can extract all folder ,sub-folders, all file and files  and folder inside sub-folder that are stored inside any jar file and opy those content into destination folder in java an while coding in eclipse platform.........
 can anybody suggest me...
 i tried many code related to zipinput stream.. storing in zipfile entities in enumeretion and writing it to detination folder. but none of it works properly......

Comment: Show us what you have coded so far.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke

```
jar xf yourApp.jar
```

from java and it will do.

**See Also**

- [Using JAR Files: The Basics](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an Eclipse based solution, select

```
File menu > Import ... > General > Archive File
```

But if you want a Java code solution, here's one using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
public static void unpackZipFile(final File archive, final File targetDirectory)
throws ZipException, IOException {
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(archive);
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        final ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
        if (zipEntry.isDirectory())
            continue;
        final File targetFile = new File(targetDirectory,
            zipEntry.getName());
        Files.createParentDirs(targetFile);
        ByteStreams.copy(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry), Files
            .newOutputStreamSupplier(targetFile).getOutput());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a helper class to do that:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/util/zip/ZipFiles.html

You can read in my blog more about the latest release and how to get it:

http://puces-blog.blogspot.com/2011/03/news-from-software-smithy.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this very simple library to **pack/unpack jar file**

[JarManager](https://bitbucket.org/ReaperSoon/maven-repo/src/367c0bcb2749/fr/stevecohen/jarmanager)

Very simple

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import fr.stevecohen.jarmanager.JarUnpacker;

class Test {
   JarUnpacker jarUnpacker = new JarUnpacker(); 
   File myfile = new File("./myfile.jar");
   File unpackDir = new File("./mydir");

   List<File> unpacked_files = jarUnpacker.unpack(myfile.getAbsolutePath(), unpackDir.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

You can also use **maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.stevecohen.jarmanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>JarManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You also need my repository

```
<repository>
    <id>repo-reapersoon</id>
    <name>ReaperSoon's repo</name>
    <url>http://repo-maven.stevecohen.fr</url>
</repository>
```

Check the last version with the link bellow to use the last dependency

Please use my [public issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/ReaperSoon/maven-repo/issues) if you find some bugs